# PCManFM 1.2.5 in Lubuntu 18.04 - custom command to batch rename all files in dir incl. subdir to subdir001, 002,

Tags: filemanager

PCManFM 1.2.5 in Lubuntu 18.04 here.

want to add a custom command to right click menu to batch rename all files in the selected dir, including all files in all subdirs, to subdir001, subdir002, ...

For example, if a directory x has subdirs abc and def containing files a1.mp3, a2.mp3, a3.mp3 each, I want the files in abc to be renamed abc001.mp3, abc002.mp3, abc003.mp3, in the same order. Same for the def dir, except to def001.mp3, etc...

How do I do this? I was searching for solutions, but they all seem to be PCManFM version dependent.

Comment: Have you checked this : https://lubuntu.me/tip-actions/ ? It says to look for custom actions in the folder `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions`.

Comment: I don't have a "file-manager" folder there.